# Is there any frame interpolation media player for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for a media player or converter with frame interpolation support. There are many for Windows, but none for Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you mean adding extra frames to increase the framerate of the video?

Comment: @FSMaxB increase the framerate remaking the missing frames

Answer (score 7):

**[slowmoVideo](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/)** is an OpenSource program that creates slow-motion videos from your footage. But it does not simply make your videos play at 0.01× speed. You can smoothly slow down and speed up your footage, optionally with motion blur.

How does slow motion work? slowmoVideo tries to find out where pixels move in the video (this information is called Optical Flow), and then uses this information to calculate the additional frames.

**Features**

- Videos in any format supported by ffmpeg can be loaded. Image sequences can also be loaded, so, if you did a timelapse with too few frames, slowmoVideo may help as well.
- **slowmoVideo** does not work with a constant slowdown factor but with curves that allow arbitrary time accelereation/deceleration/reversal.
- Motion blur can be added, as much as you want.

To install it, open a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) and enter:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brousselle/slowmovideo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install slowmovideo
```

Video tutorial on YouTube: [Tutorial: SlowmoVideo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FzZYjWeONP0).

**slowmoVideo** home page: http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/

Comment: More information here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/08/slowmo-video-timelapse-linux .