# Slow motion video software program

Tags: video, webcam, slowmovideo

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 ubuntu 64bit and I'm looking for a slow motion software package like **slowmoVideo** http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/create-classy-slow-motion-videos-in.html  I tried installing slowmoVideo but it doesn't have an installable  version for 14.04 ubuntu.  Are there any other software packages that can do the same thing.

My goal is to take 1080p video of moving water and slow it down and play it smoothly so I can see how it flows.

> **Note the PPA does not work for Ubuntu 14.04 64bit** this is the error
>
> Failed to fetch
>   W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/brousselle/slowmovideo/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   404  Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/brousselle/slowmovideo/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages
>   404  Not Found

Comment: something like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/294464/is-there-any-frame-interpolation-media-player-for-ubuntu ?

Comment: In the question I state slowmoVideo doesn't install with ubuntu 14.04

Comment: The ppa only has build for 12.04, 12.10, 13.04 and 13.10. Did you try to install the .deb, or compile from source?

Answer (score 1):

It's a command line tool, but `ffmpeg` can do slow motion.  If you don't have ffmpeg installed you will probably have to compile it from source (as far as I know there is not a ppa), but it's not difficult to do and it is worth it because ffmpeg is an excellent tool.

In terminal, you'd `cd` to the directory with your video that you want to slow down and use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf “setpts=(1/<speed>)*PTS” output.mp4
```

here's a brief explanation of the options and variables:

`-i input.mp4` sets the input video.  Note that the format doesn't have to be mp4 and the video can be named anything.

`-vf` sets the verbosity and forces the format of video.

`"setpts=(1/<speed>)*PTS"` will modify a piece of the video metadata, the presentation time stanp (PTS), to whatever you tell it to be, relative to the *current* PTS.  The `<speed>` part should be replaced with how much you want it slowed down (e.g. '`0.1` would slow it down to one-tenth speed; `0.5` would slow it to half speed, etc.).

Specify a different `output.mp4` if you don't want to overwrite the original.

I wish I could say I came up with this myself, but it mostly comes from this [blog post](http://blog.grio.com/2012/01/fast-and-slow-motion-video-with-ffmpeg.html).

Answer (score 0):

The homepage for slomovideo is [HERE](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/index.html)     and the download page to just grab a deb is [HERE](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/download.php)

I'm not on my home ubuntu machine right now, but when I try to install the deb, it will not. -Might try to compile or run in a 11.10 vm.

Update:

I got it to install by doing the following..

Next I add the 2 lines to the end of /etc/apt/sources.list like so

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list


deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
```

Add the ppa from the command line like so..

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:brousselle/slowmovideo
```

Then I edit the issue the command sudo nano `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brousselle-slowmovideo-trusty.list` and edit the two deb lines to have **precise** instead of whatever was there.

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install slowmovideo
```

Comment: Wow, installing an additional operating system to get one app to work sounds like a bit of an over kill, is there really no other app that can do this.

Comment: It is just going to pull the libs it needs. If you are unsure, just comment out the 2 lines in sources.list afterwards.